# Python: Non-Responsive multiprocessing.pool.map_async() function

Tags: python, object, multiprocessing

I have a strange problem here.

I have a python program that executes code held in seperate .py files, designed to be executed in sequence, one after another. The codes work fine, however they take too long to run. My plan was to split up processing each of these .py files amongst 4 processors using multiprocessing.pool.map_async(function, arguments) using execfile() as the function and the filename as the argument.

So anyways, when I run the code, absolutely nothing happens at all, **not even an error**.

Take a look and see if you can help me out, I run the file in SeqFile.runner(SeqFile.file).

```
class FileRunner:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
    def runner(self, file):    
        self.run = pool.map_async(execfile, file)

SeqFile = FileRunner("/Users/haysb/Dropbox/Stuart/Sample_proteins/Code/SVS_CodeParts/SequencePickler.py")
VolFile = FileRunner("/Users/haysb/Dropbox/Stuart/Sample_proteins/Code/SVS_CodeParts/VolumePickler.py")
CWFile = FileRunner("/Users/haysb/Dropbox/Stuart/Sample_proteins/Code/SVS_CodeParts/Combine_and_Write.py")
(SeqFile.runner(SeqFile.file))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here - I'm guessing you never used `multiprocessing` before.

One of your problems is that you fire off an async operation but never wait for it to end.  If you *did* wait for it to end, you'd get more info.  For example, add:

```
result = SeqFile.run.get()
```

Do that, and you'll see the exception raised in the child process:  you're mapping `execfile` over the *string* bound to `file`, so `execfile` sees one character at a time.  `execfile` barfs when the first thing it tries to do is (in effect):

```
execfile("/")
```

`apply_async()` would make a lot more sense, or `map_async()` passed a list of all the files you want to run.

Etc - this gets tedious ;-)

### Specifics

Let's get rid of the irrelevant cruft here, and show a complete executable program.  I have three files `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py`.  Here's `a.py`:

```
print "I'm A!"
```

The other two are the obvious variations.

Here's my entire driver:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp

    files = ["a.py", "b.py", "c.py"]
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    pool.imap_unordered(execfile, files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

That's all it takes, and prints (some permutation of):

```
I'm A!
I'm B!
I'm C!
```

`imap_unordered()` splits the list of files up among the worker processes, and doesn't care ("unordered") which order they run in.  That's maximally efficient.  Note that I restricted the number of workers to 2, just to show that it works fine even though there are more files (3) than worker processes (2).

You can get any of the `Pool` functions to work similarly.  If you *have* ;-) to use `map_async()`, for example, replace the `imap_unordered()` call with:

```
async = pool.map_async(execfile, files)
async.get()
```

Or:

```
asyncs = [pool.apply_async(execfile, (fn,)) for fn in files]
for a in asyncs:
    a.get()
```

Clearer?  Keep it as simple as possible at first.

Comment: So I used apply_async, and added this line after (SeqFile.runner(SeqFile.file)), result = SeqFile.run.get(timeout=None). I now get this error TypeError: execfile() takes at most 3 arguments (81 given). Which from what I understand, means that it is taking each character as an argument (given that there are 81 characters in the string I am using). When I go back to using map_async, I get the error you spoke of---IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/' --- as in it is taking the very first character as an argument. Is there any easy way to get around this? execfile() usually works with strings.

Comment: Try `.apply_async(execfile, args=(file,))`.  All these functions expect an iterable producing arguments.  If you pass a string directly, that's an iterable, producing one character at a time.  The expected way is what I just showed, passing a `tuple` of arguments (in this case, a tuple containing a single value).  But better still to use `map_async()` passing a tuple of *all* the file paths.  Putting each file path in its own class instance is just complicating your life ;-)

Comment: OK, this is working much better for me now. Out of curiosity, is this how multiprocessing meant to be used? I have seen people use this just for a singular function as well, rather than an entire code.

Comment: @user2631970, `mp` is meant to be used whenever multiple processes are a good approach ;-) Most uses I've seen involve some communication between the main program and the workers, like producer/consumer problems with several workers taking descriptions of work off an `mp.Queue`, and passing results back to the main program via another `Queue`. For your specific example, I guess most folks would use the `subprocess` module instead, explicitly invoking (some spelling of) `python.exe <path_to_py_file>`. Your application is clever! :-)